# How do I warm up an actor's state from database when starting up?

Tags: persistence, akka.net

My requirement is to start a long running process to tag all the products that are expired. This is run every night at 1:00 AM. The customers may be accessing some of the products on the website, so they have instances around the time when the job is run. The others are in the persistent media, not yet having instances because the customers are not accessing them.

Where should I hook up the logic to read the latest state of an actor from a persistent media and create a brand new actor? Should I have that call in the **Prestart** override method? If so, how can I tell the **ProductActor** that a new actor being created.

Or should I send a message to the **ProductActor** like **LoadMeFromAzureTable** which will load the state from the persistent media after an actor being created?

Comment: Am I understanding you to mean that you are creating an actor for every product??

Comment: Creating an actor per product will help scaling. I also don't want to keep them in the system because it is a job, so after the job is done, all the product actors need to be killed.

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to do it depending on what you need, as opposed to there being precisely one "right" answer.

You could use a [Persistent Actor](http://getakka.net/docs/Persistence) to recover state from a durable store automatically on startup (or in case of crash, to recover). Or, if you don't want to use that module (still in beta as of July 2015), you could do it yourself one of two ways:

1) You could load your state in `PreStart`, but I'd only go with this if you can make the operation async via your database client and use [the `PipeTo` pattern](https://petabridge.com/blog/akkadotnet-async-actors-using-pipeto/) to send the results back to yourself incrementally. But if you need to have ALL the state resident in memory before you start doing work, then you need to...

2) Make a [finite state machine using behavior switching](http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Switchable%20Behaviors). Start in a gated state, send yourself a message to load your data, and stash everything that comes in. Then switch to a receiving state and unstash all messages when your state is done loading. This is the approach I prefer.

Example (just mocking the DB load with a `Task`):

```cs
public class ProductActor : ReceiveActor, IWithUnboundedStash
{
    public IStash Stash { get; set; }

    public ProductActor()
    {
        // begin in gated state
        BecomeLoading();
    }

    private void BecomeLoading()
    {
        Become(Loading);
        LoadInitialState();
    }

    private void Loading()
    {
        Receive<DoneLoading>(done =>
        {
            BecomeReady();
        });

        // stash any messages that come in until we're done loading
        ReceiveAny(o =>
        {
            Stash.Stash();
        });
    }

    private void LoadInitialState()
    {
        // load your state here async & send back to self via PipeTo
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // database loading task here
            return new Object();
        }).ContinueWith(tr =>
        {
            // do whatever (e.g. error handling)
            return new DoneLoading();
        }).PipeTo(Self);
    }

    private void BecomeReady()
    {
        Become(Ready);
        // our state is ready! put all those stashed messages back in the mailbox
        Stash.UnstashAll();
    }

    private void Ready()
    {
        // handle those unstashed + new messages...

        ReceiveAny(o =>
        {
            // do whatever you need to do...
        });
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Marker interface.
/// </summary>
public class DoneLoading {}
```